# Philips TV: Connect MacBook shared folder to TV

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, television

I have an issue: Connect Macbook and Philips TV.

I want to browse Macbook shared folder in Philips TV, but it cannot be done as easily as on Windows (uh)

Maximum what I've found after an hour of searching in google: Smart TV Share, program in App Store. It allows Philips TV to browse only in Pictures folder.

I also try to change target directory of this program by settings, but nothing seems to changed. (No settings available for user :( )

Please, if anyone knows solution, help me!

Answer (score -1):

try plex ;)
it creates a media server on the network and you reach the shared contents from your smart TV like a flash drive. it works on my LG smart TV

Comment: This is not an answer to the question - it is an answer to a completely different question